# How to include library in rubymine unit tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rubymine, ruby-1.9.2

I have an Rails 3 App, here i have a unit test in test/unit/test.rb

```
require "test/unit"
require "lib/feeder"

class LinkParserTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_with_single_host
    **some code**
    assert_equal(links,Feeder.link_parser(entry_summary,host))
  end
```

if i run test in console by using `ruby -I. test/unit/link_parser_test.rb` command everything works perfectly
but if i run test in RubyMine it says `require: no such file to load -- lib/feeder (LoadError)`

what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it, rubymine runing ruby -Itest test/unit/link_parser_test.rb command (so it starts in test folder) i had to change require to require "./lib/feeder" and it works normaly